# Ubuntu 15.10 after restart Wi-Fi, usb ports, LAN, not working! Please help

Tags: networking, usb, upgrade, updates, 15.10

I have a laptop Notebook HP 15-g011la here the specifications: 
http://www8.hp.com/mx/es/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7052369#!tab=specs

I do not know what happened yesterday my computer was working fine, I didn't install anything, neither messing with configurations, just did sudo apt-get update, and then upgrade, and i used my laptop normally for about an hour then shut down, and when i tryed to use it today a lot of things were not working: Wi-Fi, LAN, USB ports, SD cards reader, and DVD.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed a new kernel, which doesn't support your configuration. Check if you have the previous kernel listed in the boot list and try loading it to see if it still works.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. That solved my problem!!!!!!!!!. I was about to format my computer  but you answer.  Thank you !

Comment: Happy to help. In the future pay attention to what you upgrade, it will help you deal with any issues that arise.