# No network after upgrade to 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, upgrade

I upgraded my server to 14.04.3 LTS by doing "sudo do-release-upgrade". It all seemed to work fine, but after rebooting I have no network at all. I can't find the computers on my LAN or anything on the internet from my server, and I can't find my server from my other computers.

I don't even know where to start trouble shooting...

Answer (score 1):

[I had a similar problem yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711299/ubuntu-15-10-after-restart-wi-fi-usb-ports-lan-not-working-please-help/711375?noredirect=1#comment1047104_711375). 
As Tomasz suggested it can possibly be a problem with the kernel you should reboot your pc and try to boot with a different kernel. That may help you.

**How to boot with a different Kernel**

When your computer starts if you have two or more operating systems you should see a screen like this (if you don't hold press **shif** or **esc** keys at the very start of your computer)

[image]

```
Select Advanced options for Ubuntu
```

Now you probably will see two or more different kernels:

[image]

> Select an older version, remember which one you choose, you may need to try this more than once

Once you boot with a different kernel you may be able to use your network do a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and restart your computer to see if now you can boot without choosing the kernel.

That worked for me.

[If you want more detailed tutorial you can read this howtogeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/196520/grub2-101-how-to-access-and-use-your-linux-distributions-boot-loader/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! When trying it I stumbled on another problem, though... Just before I see this screen I get the message "Keyboard failure" and in this screen I can't use the keyboard at all, so I can't choose another entry. When the OS has booted the keyboard works again... Any suggestions...?

Comment: I have never had that problem, do you have a live usb with ubuntu ? You can use it like if you were trying to install ubuntu but it gives you an option to repair ubuntu

Comment: Also, you can boot from the live usb and NOT install ubuntu, once there your computer should work and you can try to download and run grub repair

Comment: if you don't know how to do those things please let me know

Comment: I managed to get the keyboard working. Googling I found out that it's a hardware problem with my Dell server. Powering down, disconnecting everything else than the keyboard, draining the capacitors and then restarting did the trick. Now I'm trying your suggested procedure - I come back in a couple of minutes when the upgrade is finished and I know if it worked.   :-)

Comment: I booted with an older Linux version and managed to get internet access. I did apt-get update, upgrade and dist-upgrade and then rebooted with the latest version again. But unfortunately it didn't help. I still get the message "connect: network is unreachable" when trying to reach anything outside my server, e.g. doing a ping.

Comment: I downloaded the release and burnt it to a CD, booted from that and chose repair in the menu. After that the screen went completely black and nothing more happened...

Comment: If you computer works with an older kernel you can delete the latest with synaptic

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by some more googling!

In /etc/network/interfaces the following line was commented out:

# iface eth0 inet dhcp

I removed the "#", rebooted and got network access again!