# Repair a PC without network, cd, nor usb

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, usb, mount

Here is my issue. i am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Since my last apt-get upgrade something went wrong and my network card does not work anymore, and it's impossible to mount any usb stick.

as i said in the title, i can't read cd or dvd. I do not have anything worth to be saved on it.

I am ready to ear any solution that could save my machine ^^. even a total wipeout of my SSD.

I thought if i can get the network back, i will be able to download the drivers :) or if i can have the usb back, i can get the drivers then get them down. or last solution re-install my computer.

But i can't do any of it.

Thanks for your ideas and help :)

Sorry of i can't show you my CLI results since i am not on my computer :(

**Details Wifi**

```
ifconfig -a
```

Shows me Lo that's it.

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A Network
```

show me than no kernel driver is in use

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Signals me an error, that it does not exist. Impossible to modprobe iwlwifi / iwldvm / iwlmvm (if it has any sense)

**Details USB**

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A USB
```

Shows me the kernel Driver is loaded.

```
lsusb
```

Shows me a new device but without any name on it But i can't mount it.

Comment: Presumably this is a software error so you could reboot off a live CD or USB? Also worth telling us if you have a separate /home/ partition, in case you need a reinstall?

Comment: I already had a similar you can find an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/711625/no-network-after-upgrade-to-14-04-3-lts/711641?noredirect=1#comment1047577_711641

Comment: @MarkWilliams i can't use any CD or USB, so i can't do a live reboot.

Comment: @albertoefg Thank you, your link helped me a lot.
 i have recovered full functionnality from an old version, but i always need to do the manipulation to select an older version... I will save all i need and reinstall. Thank You Sir !

Comment: Before you do that i recomend you to do a sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade after i did that my kernel was upgraded again and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution found is enough for me but might be not for others.

You have to reboot and hold shift or esc to select advanced options for ubuntu
and select an older kernel version.

Then the network and usb were back.

The link given by albertoefg ([No network after upgrade to 14.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711625/no-network-after-upgrade-to-14-04-3-lts/711641?noredirect=1#comment1047577_711641))

does not allow me to just reboot as it is.
I have to do the manipulation every time.

it's not a problem for me i can just re-install everything.
Hope it will help you !